# Problem setting default selection on a Flex 3 List

Tags: list, flex3

Hi I've got a list and the selectedIndex doesn't seem to have any effect. Is the alternatingItemColors causing a problem?

I've got a panel with this list and a few radio buttons. I've set the defaults on the radio buttons, but I'm having problems setting 2010 as the default selection in the list.

```
<mx:List  

    id="myList" 
        width="120" 
        height="80"
        alternatingItemColors="[0xFFFFFF, 0xEEEEEE]"
        selectedIndex="0">

     <mx:dataProvider>
            <mx:Object label="2010" data="myData1" />
            <mx:Object label="2009" data="myData2" />
            <mx:Object label="2008" data="myData3" />
     </mx:dataProvider>

  <mx:List>
```

I also tried adding: creationComplete="myList.selectedIndex=0", but that didn't work, either.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Comment: This works just fine for me when copied/pasted, the first item shows as selected when run.  The only issue is that your closing tag for the List is missing the slash, it should be </mx:List>, but you'd get a compile error for that.  Anything else in the surrounding code or elsewhere that could be causing this that you'd like to share with us?

Comment: Hi Wade, Thanks for the help. You're right it works fine. I had a problem with another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I fiured it out. I was setting the selectedIndex in the component correctly. But, I had another function acting on the instance, which was causing the problem.

Thank you

-Laxmidi